# Do I need to add shipping address every time whenever I place a new order in Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, rest-api

**STEP 1** - Using REST API I created a customer,And in address data I passed
    default shipping and billing true

- `"defaultShipping": true,`
- `"defaultBilling": true,`

**STEP 2** - In GET customer detail API it returns true value for `defaultShipping` and `defaultBilling`

**STEP 3** - But when I fetch the shipping methods using `rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods` API to place and Order it return me the error

> "message": "Shipping address not set."

**So Magento 2 REST API is not fetching  `defaultShipping` address value.**

And I need to add shipping address every time whenever I place a new order to fetch shipping methods and charge with this API.

```
POST http://host/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods
```

> Is there any Alternate solution available to pass `defaultShipping`
>   address data to get shipping-methods and shipping-charge **without adding new
>   address** every time I place a new order ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Magento 2 have API - which we can select from existing address from customer account addresses API, so
>   customer don't need to add address every time whenever he/she places a
>   new order.

**quoteShippingMethodManagementV1**

Interface `ShippingMethodManagementInterface`

```
POST /V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id
```

**Data**

```
{
  "addressId": 0
}
```